# Academic Term Start and End dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, data-warehouse, star-schema

[image]I have academic term start and end dates for each term (spring, summer, fall) for academic years ranging from 1975 to 2020 in D_Term dimension. For example:

```
 2017-01-16  to 2017-05-18  (Spring)   
 2017-06-05 to 2017-08-04  (Summer) 
 2017-08-24  to 2017-12-20  (Fall)
```

My current problem is that I need to create a make up table where the start and end term are as:
 01/01 to 05/31 (spring)
and for summer term it is 06/01 to 08/31
and for fall term it is 09/01 to 12/31
this needs to reflect irrespective what the academic year is.The idea is to eliminate the gaps between acad term end date (spring) and acad term start date (summer) between two consecutive terms.

I have no clue how to go about it. Any ideas are welcome!

Thank you

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

First a little test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #dates (TermStart DATE, TermEnd DATE, Term VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #dates (TermStart, TermEnd, Term)
VALUES ('2017-01-16','2017-05-18','spring'),
('2017-06-05','2017-08-04','summer'),
('2017-08-24','2017-12-20','fall')
```

And then the solution:

```
SELECT 
    Term
    , TermStart
    , TermEnd
    , NewStart = CASE WHEN LAG(DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DAY,TermEnd)*-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,TermEnd)))) OVER (ORDER BY TermStart ASC) = DATEPART(MONTH,TermStart) 
                        THEN DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(dd,DATEPART(DAY,TermStart)*-1,TermStart)) )
                        ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(dd,DATEPART(DAY,TermStart)*-1,TermStart)) 
                        END
    , NewEnd = DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DAY,TermEnd)*-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,TermEnd))
FROM #dates
```

Results:

```
Term    TermStart   TermEnd     NewStart    NewEnd
------------------------------------------------------
spring  2017-01-16  2017-05-18  2017-01-01  2017-05-31
summer  2017-06-05  2017-08-04  2017-06-01  2017-08-31
fall    2017-08-24  2017-12-20  2017-09-01  2017-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked :)

```
with cte as
(
SELECT 
   New_Academic_Term_Start_DTTM = CASE WHEN Academic_Term_Code like 'SPRING'
                                then 
      concat(year(Academic_Term_Start_DTTM),'-','01','-','01')
                                WHEN Academic_Term_Code like 'SUMMER'
                                then 
      concat(year(Academic_Term_Start_DTTM),'-','06','-','01')
                                WHEN Academic_Term_Code like 'FALL'
                                then 
      concat(year(Academic_Term_Start_DTTM),'-','08','-','21')
                                end 
      from D_Term
)
select   
   convert(datetime2(7),New_Academic_Term_End_DTTM,120) as 
  New_Academic_Term_End_DTTM
   from cte
```